# Asymptotic Expansion of Integrals

Tags: mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory

I am considering the Integral $$\int_{0}^{\infty}dt\frac{e^{-t}t^{s}}{1+\lambda x t}$$
I am trying to have an  asymptotic expansion of the above said integral. The process of integration by parts somehow is not working for me. If any other methods for the asymptotic expansion of the integral works, please help me out.

Comment: Saddle point method: Expand the logarithm of the integrand around its maximum, clearly this will yield a Gaussian type integral.  The systematic way to do this involves defining a new variable u such that the integrand becomes exactly equal to exp(-u^2), instead of the handwaving way where you have higher order terms from the expansion in the exponential that you need to  expand further. After the conformal transform to u, you get th equivalent of such terms directly in the Jacobian dt/du.

Comment: Asymptotic in which variable? In what limit? What is kept constant?